# Funções depreciadas do PHP 5 para migrar para o PHP 7, função @

Tags: php

Estou tendo que migrar um projeto todo feito em PHP 5 para PHP 7, ao rodar uma ferramenta de diagnóstico, ela aponta que algumas funções utilizam o `@` e estão depreciadas por exemplo:

```
/**
 * Creates a copy of a class object
 * @param $object (object) class object to be cloned
 * @return cloned object
 * @since 4.5.029 (2009-03-19)
 * @public static
 */
public static function objclone($object) {
    if (($object instanceof Imagick) AND (version_compare(phpversion('imagick'), '3.0.1') !== 1)) {
        // on the versions after 3.0.1 the clone() method was deprecated in favour of clone keyword
        return @$object->clone();
    }
    return @clone($object);
}
```

Note que esta sendo usado o `@` para lidar com isso.
Preciso alterar o fonte de forma segura para o sistema continuar funcionando normalmente, como posso lidar com os casos que ultilizam o `@`?

Comment: Em algum momento é utilizado o `imagick` nessas versões antigas?

Comment: Sim, ainda é utilizado.
Eu sei que se der erro ao executar o `clone()` de um objeto inexistente ele da falta error

Comment: errata *fatal error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O operador `@` é utilizado para suprimir mensagens de erro. Pode até ser que o código que dependa desse método já esteja errado a tempos, mesmo no PHP 5.

Nesse caso eu removeria o `@` para garantir que tudo está funcionando. É possível incluir outras verificações de tipo a fim de garantir que ao chegar no `clone` não aconteça maiores problemas.

Você pode por exemplo adicionar um *type hinting* de `object` para garantir que somente objetos serão passados para esse método (funciona a partir do PHP 7.2):

```
public static function objclone(object $object) {

}
```

Nesse caso ao usar um tipo inválido você saberá onde precisa arrumar.

Outra abordagem um pouco menos disruptiva é verificar o tipo da variável e se não for um objeto retornar a própria variável, pois o `clone` só funciona com objetos e retornar uma variável primitiva é semelhante ao comportamento do clone (no PHP só objetos recebem uma referencia na atribuição):

```
public static function objclone($object) {
    if (!is_object($object)) {
        return $object;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Outra opção que pode dar mais trabalho, verifique se você realmente precisa fazer um clone dos objetos. Além de melhorar o consumo de memória, seu código ficará mais legível. E caso precise use diretamente `clone` ao invés de chamar a função.

Por último, mas não menos importante, confirme a versão correta do Imagick. De acordo com a [documentação desse método](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.clone.php), ele foi descontinuado na versão 3.1.0, e não na versão 3.0.1.

Tente alterar seu código para utilizar essa versão. Num compilado, seu método pode ficar assim:

```
public static function objclone($object) {
    if (!is_object($object)) {
        // If is not an object, return the variable itself
        return $object;
    }

    if (($object instanceof Imagick) && (version_compare(phpversion('imagick'), '3.1.0') !== 1)) {
       // clone() method was deprecated in favor of clone keyword
       // see https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.clone.php
       return $object->clone();
    }

    return clone $object;
}
```